# Will using Socket.io instead of normal ajax calls prevent a server from running out of TCP sockets?

Tags: node.js, sockets, concurrency, nginx, socket.io

I'm trying to set up a server that can handle a high sustained amount of simultaneous requests. I found that at a certain point, the server won't be able to recycle "old" TCP connections quickly enough to accommodate extreme amounts of requests.

Do websockets eliminate or decrease the amount of tcp connections that a server needs to handle, and are they a good alternative to "normal" requests?

Comment: It sounds like you may have a long "keep alive" setting for your current webserver. Modifying it may solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Websockets are persistent connections so it really depends on what you're talking about. The way socket.io uses XHR is different from a typical ajax call in that it hangs onto the request for as long as possible before sending a response. It's a technique called long-polling and It's trying to simulate a persistent connection by never letting go of the request. When the request is about to timeout it sends a response and a new request is initiated immediately which it hangs onto yet again, and the cycle continues.

So I guess if you're getting flooded with connections because of ajax calls then that's probably because your client code is polling the server at some sort of interval. This means that even idle clients will be hitting your server with fury because of this polling. If that's the case then yes, socket.io will reduce your number of connections because it tries to hang onto one single connection per client for as long as possible.

These days I recommend socket.io over doing plain ajax requests. Socket.io is designed to be performant with whatever transport it settles on. The way it gracefully degrades based on what connection is possible is great and means your server will be overloaded as little as possible while still reaching as wide an audience as it can.